# I have to write a program to sort 5 input numbers in ascending order with using only "if" conditions

Tags: python

I've been told to write a program to sort 5 input numbers in ascending order. I have done the basic solution for three numbers but I am confused in what to do for 5 numbers. Any help?

```
a = float(input("Enter a: "))
b = float(input("Enter b: "))
c = float(input("Enter c: "))
if a < b:
    if b < c:
        print (a, "<", b, "<", c)
    else:
        if a < c:
            print (a, "<", c, "<", b)
        else:
            print (c, "<", a, "<", b)
else:
    if c < b:
        print (c, "<", b, "<", a)
    else:
        if c < a:
            print (b, "<", c, "<", a)
        else:
            print (b, "<", a, "<", c)
```

Comment: Assuming you can't use `while` or `for`, nor `sorted` or `list`s of any kind, this would still be easier to do an an unrolled bubble sort, where you swap values until `a` is the smallest and `e` is the largest. `if b < a: a, b = b, a`, `if c < a: a, c = c, a`, etc., etc. That said, it's a nuts assignment to make you hand jam that many tests (sure, technically you could just write four test-and-swaps, then copy them down four times, but teaching you to do copy-n-paste programming is poor form). Are you sure you're not allowed to use *any* other constructs?

Comment: What specifically is your point of confusion?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution meeting your requirements would be an unrolled bubble sort that swapped elements enough times to guarantee the smallest element was in `a` and the largest in `e`:

```
if b < a:
    a, b = b, a
if c < b:
    b, c = c, b
if d < c:
    c, d = d, c
if e < d:
    d, e = e, d
```

Copy and paste that three more times (so each pass adjusts at least one element not in the correct position to be in the correct position; the way it's written some of the code could be omitted from each subsequent pass, but it's easier to just copy and paste and do pointless work than remove one more test from each pass), then end with:

```
print(f'{a} <= {b} <= {c} <= {d} <= {e}')
```

It's a *really* ugly solution (you should never copy and paste code like that in real life), but if you're super-restricted on what you're allowed to do, it works.